# Get properties of an object from a function inside this object

Tags: javascript

Assume I have an object and an example of how I would like to get a property `height` from this object inside a function that is inside the object too:

```
function Chart(element) {
    return {
        width: element.clientWidth,
        height: 400,
        loadLegend: function (data) {
            doSomething(this.height)
        }
    }
};
```

This code doesn't work, as it's just an illustration to what I need to achieve.
Please advise how I can get that property from the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Chart(element) {
    var chart = {
        width: element.clientWidth,
        height: 400
    };
    chart.loadLegend = function (data) {
        doSomething(chart.height)
    };
    return chart;
};
```